# Generate React form fields from JSON

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i am trying to generate a form from JSON config. I am parsing the JSON and using map functions to generate material UI TextField components.
But issue is that the generated  components do not get rendered, instead the whole JS code appears on screen. Not sure why.

here is my code in 2 files:

FormConfig.js:

```
  "Form1": {   
    "fields": [
      {
        uiElement: "TextField",
        id: '"standard-name"',
        name: "'asdada'",
        className: "{classes.textField}",
        value: "{this.state.name}",
        onChange: '{this.handleChange("name")}',
        required: true,
        margin: '"normal"'
      },
      {
        uiElement: "TextField",
        id: '"standard-uncontrolled"',
        name: '"asda"',
        label: '"Required"',
        className: '"{classes.textField}"',
        value: '"asd"',
        onChange: "{}",
        required: true,
        margin: '"normal"'
      }
   ]
  },
  "OtherForm":
  {
      "fields": [{}, {}]
  }
}

const getForm = formName => {
  return FormConfig[formName].fields.map(field => `<${field.uiElement} `+
    Object.keys(field).filter(k => k !== 'uiElement')
      .map(k => {
        return k + "=" + field[k];
      })
      .join(" ") + `/>`
  )
}

export default getForm;
```

TestForm.js

```
class TextFields extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Cat in the Hat',
    age: '',
    multiline: 'Controlled',
    currency: 'EUR',
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">

        {
            getForm("Form1")
        }

        <TextField
          required
          id="standard-required"
          label="Required"
          defaultValue="Hello World"
          className={classes.textField}
          margin="normal"
        />
```

I was expecting that the call to `getForm()` would have rendered my fields, but instead it spits out this on the web page. Am I doing something wrong?

```
<TextField id="standard-name" name='asdada' className={classes.textField} value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange("name")} required=true margin="normal"/><TextField id="standard-uncontrolled" name="asda" label="Required" className="{classes.textField}" value="asd" onChange={} required=true margin="normal"/><TextField id="standard-read-only-input" name="asd" label="Read Only" className={classes.textField} value="asd" onChange={} required=false margin="normal" InputProps={{readOnly: true}}/><TextField id="standard-dense" name="w3rg" label="Dense" className={classNames(classes.textField, classes.dense)} value="sdas" onChange={} required=false margin="dense"/>
```

Comment: Your getForm function returns a string and not react elements.

Comment: you can't return '<' + field.uiElement + '>'... You need to return the real component, something like: 'if(field.uiElement == 'TextField') return <TextField {...field}/>. If you have several components, you can use a switch() structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to return the component at mapping:

```
const getForm = formName => {
  return FormConfig[formName].fields.map(field => evalComponent(field))
}

const evalComponent = field => {
    let { uiElement, ...props } = field
    switch(uiElement) {
        case 'TextField':
            return <TextField {...props}/>
        default:
            return false
    }
}
```

Comment: and, for the field value and onChange, You'll need to increment the logic with state and setState. I used a simple format with the attribute "name" in my forms

Comment: Thanks @JoaozitoPolo. I am able to render the components. However, like you said, some additional logic is needed to handle the value and onChange and className. I understand that THIS keyword cannot work inside the JSON, but if not, it would mean moving he above function in the TestForm.js file and applying all the logic there. Is that what you are suggesting?

Comment: You can put the context on that render... the getForm can receive (formName, state, setState), and evalComponent can receive (field, state and setState)